# Problemas al decodificar mayúsculas en UTF 8

Tags: php, utf-8, fpdf

estoy trabajando en un archivo que genera un pdf y empleo la librería fpdf, en este documento intente decodificar los caracteres utf8 que previamente fueron codificados al realizar el registro en la BD y funciona para caracteres en minúscula como á,é,ñ pero si es mayúscula (Ñ,Á,É) no las convierte correctamente 
EJ:  á é í ó ú ñ ?‘ ?• ?‰ ?• ?“ ?š

Como podría solucionarlo?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Dices que los datos vienen de una BD? ¿Si muestras el mismo contenido que pasas al PDF en una página (HTML), se muestran correctamente los acentos en mayúsculas?

Comment: si claro se visualiza bien (á é í ó ú ñ Ñ Á É Í Ó Ú)

Comment: Disculpa pero aún no puedo escribir comentarios. ¿Probaste pasar los valores a minúsculas, pasarles un utf8_decode o utf8_encode y ver el resultado?